# virtualization with decent performance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, debian, virtualization

At my work we have a couple of surface pro 2017, They are all the same i7, 512gb ssd and 16gb of ram variant. They only run windows 10 but an upcomming project requires the use of linux for the team. I installed the guest additions on both machines. and gave them 8gbs of memory. with 128 vram(the max).

So my first thought was to use virtualbox to just run an ubuntu 17.04 or debian stretch install. But this proved to have incredibly horrendous performance. Literally the mouse lagging behind. So my next try was to just install ubuntu 17.04 as dual boot. But ubuntu won't work. Network times out after a 2 or 3 minutes and there is no way to reconnect.

Now my next try was to use the hyper-v but even on the gen 2 hyper-v machine the performance is still really bad. The mouse is lagging with something like 10fps. Even when instaling the recommendended integration software.

Debian or ubuntu is required unfortunately since the the software we will be using is only useable on those platforms.

Is there any way I could fix the performance on these virtual machines or is there another avenue I haven't tried?

As the comments added WSL could have been a good option. But the applications we need to run need 3d visualization. We are going to work with ROS. And for instance rviz package within ros is reported to not work correctly with ROS. Also we are using socat to create virtual serial ports which also doesn't work in WSL.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Rather oddly I can see some advice suggesting you change the power plan options to high performance. Check the CPU speed to see if it is being limited while the Virtualbox VM is running.

Comment: have you tried backing up the data / windows side and then just installing ubuntu as native? Does it work fine then , if so, then try a dual install of windows but installed "second"...

Comment: Do the team specifically need Linux or would the Windows Subsystem for Linux do the job?

Comment: @Mokubai Sadly the application requires a 3d tool which doesn't work in WSL.

Comment: If you need all the performance you can then it would probably be worth browsing the Suface Linux subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/ . I get the impression that Ubuntu with a "fixed" kernel might be a runner.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Linux Bash Shell, also called Ubuntu on Windows.

This isn’t a virtual machine, but Microsoft that allows you to run on Windows the Bash shell and the exact same binaries you’d normally run on Ubuntu.

See [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/).

If your problem with it is running a graphical interface,
many references are available for making it work.
See for example
[How to use X Windows with Emacs on Windows 10 Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182483/how-to-use-x-windows-with-emacs-on-windows-10-bash).

If the Linux Bash Shell is not a solution, it is also possible to dual-boot
Ubuntu on the Surface Pro.
See for example [Dual boot Surface Pro with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu).

Comment: I already suggested this in a comment and it was declined due to not being what was required. Admittedly this restriction should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Mokubai: I would like some more info from the poster about why it doesn't work. AFAIK even X Windows can be made to work on it. It's worthwhile for the poster to try and explore this solution, since it will solve his virtualization problem. As you are the first to suggest it, I will delete this answer if you will put up your own.

Comment: I'm fine with you posting an answer, especially if you can mention how to get X going and how to host a native GUI app on it, I'm not precious about keeping an answer to myself... I was more mentioning that it had been discounted, if it is in fact a usable solution then that would be good to know.

Comment: Looking at it running GUI apps on WSL sounds painful and buggy and probably doesn't have a good graphics transition layer going yet. From what little I've read it sounds workable but highly dependant on the app you are using and I suspect accelerated 3d (implied by their comment to me) is going to be off the cards. As I say, it would be nice if this was an option though.

Comment: @Mokubai: Making graphical apps work is perhaps indeed the poster's problem. The example reference I added above does not sound too painful and uses MobaXterm, with which I have experience and know it is a very good product. We really need more info from the poster about what didn't work.

Comment: @Mokubai: In the case this doesn't work at all, I added a link how to install Ubuntu itself on Surface Pro. Although the Surface Pro 2017 is newer than the link ...

Comment: Yes I added the reason we can't use WSL. It's not only graphical. But that is the mean reason.

Comment: WSL is supposed to be almost a total port of Ubuntu. But if it's not good enough, you can dual-boot the real Ubuntu.